# Possible to alias a belongs_to association in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model with a `belongs_to` association:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :vendor
end
```

So I can call `car.vendor`. But I also want to call `car.company`! So, I have the following:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :vendor
  def company
    vendor
  end
end
```

but that doesn't solve the assignment situation `car.company = 'ford'`, so I need to create another method for that. Is there a simple `alias` mechanism I can use for associations? Can I just use `alias_method :company, :vendor` and `alias_method :company=, :vendor=`?

Answer (score 82):

No it doesn't look for company_id for instance change your code as follows

### In Rails3

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :vendor
   belongs_to :company, :class_name => :Vendor,:foreign_key => "vendor_id"
end
```

### In Rails4

We can use alias attribute.

```
alias_attribute :company, :vendor
```

Comment: Unfortunately reflect_on_association doesn't work with the latter.

Comment: The rails 4 syntax is concise, but works if your syntax is picture perfect.  By doing `belongs_to :company, class_name: :Vendor, foreign_key: "vendor_id" ` you actually have a better handle on the syntax of your variables and can use that as an intermediary step to "succincty'

Answer (score 33):

In Rails 4, you should simply be able to add `alias_attribute :company, :vendor` to your model.

Comment: Good tip! Just to point: using `alias_attribute` makes still possible to access both the attributes `company` and `vendor`, while using **only**  the relation `belongs_to :company, :class_name => :Vendor,:foreign_key => "vendor_id"` hides the attribute `vendor`.

Comment: This is deprecated in Rails 7.1 and will be removed in Rails 7.2

Answer (score 13):

**Short Version:**

1. Generate model with migration

   `$ rails generate model Car vendor:references name:string ...`
2. Add following line in `Car` model i.e `car.rb` file

   ```
   class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :company, :class_name => 'Vendor', :foreign_key => 'vendor_id'
   end
   ```
3. Now you have `@car.company` instance method.

For a Detailed explanation read ahead *[Optional if you understood the above !!]*

**Detailed Version:**

The model `Car` will have an association with the model `Vendor` (which is obvious). So there should be a `vendor_id` in the table `cars`.

1. In order to make sure that the field `vendor_id` is present in the `cars` table run the following on the command line. This will generate the right migration. The `vendor:references` is important. You can have any number of attributes after that.

   `$ rails generate model Car vendor:references name:string`
2. Or else in the existing migration for `create_table :cars` just add the line `t.references :vendor`

   ```
   class CreateCars < ActiveRecord::Migration
     def change
       create_table :cars do |t|
         t.string :name
         ...
         t.references :vendor
         t.timestamps
       end
     end
   end
   ```
3. The final thing that you need to do is edit the model `Car`. So add this code to your `car.rb` file

   ```
   class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :company, :class_name => 'Vendor', :foreign_key => 'vendor_id'
   end
   ```

After you do the third step you will get the following instance methods for the model `Car` provided by Rails Associations

1. `@car.company`

   - When you do `@car.company` it will return a `#<Vendor ...>` object. To find that `#<Vendor ...>` object it will go look for the `vendor_id` column in the `cars` table because you have mentioned `:foreign_key => 'vendor_id'`
   - You can set the company for a car instance by writing

     ```
     @car.company = @vendor || Vendor.find(params[:id]) #whichever Vendor object you want
     @car.save
     ```

     This will save the `id` of that `Vendor` object in the `vendor_id` field of the `cars` table.

Thank You.

Answer (score 4):

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :vendor
  belongs_to :company, :class_name => :Vendor
end
```

Comment: wouldn't this look for a `company_id` field in the database?

Comment: No, at least in Rails 4.2. After some testing, it appears that the column name is determined by the class used, not the association's attribute name.

So `belongs_to :company, class_name: :Vendor` would search for a column in your table named `vendor_id` - whereas not specifying the class_name option will auto-resolve to use class name `Company` and would search for a `company_id` column. Nevertheless, it still may be considered better practice to supply the `foreign_key:` option to help eliminate future headaches.